# Cannot load dll file in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using FLANN code to make project. The first, I build FLANN code using cmake and I have a folder lib contains dll file and lib file (successful). After that,
I make a project and link configure for my code:

```
Additional include Directories :  <path to include file>
Additional Library Directories : <path to lib file>
Additional Dependencies: flann.lib
```

I build successfully but when I run it, visual has notify :
The program cannot start because flann.dll is missing from your computer....
And terminal has:

```
'FLANN_Test2.exe': Loaded 'D:\Computer Vision\FLANN_Test2\Debug\FLANN_Test2.exe', Symbols loaded.
'FLANN_Test2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FLANN_Test2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'FLANN_Test2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[7092] FLANN_Test2.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
```

What is happen? Can you help me edit it. I am using win 32 and visual 32 bit.

Comment: where is flann.dll? Is it in the path?

Comment: This is file in lib folder.

Comment: Are you try to run in Debug mode? could you go `Debug` > `Start Without Debugging` and let me know the result.

Comment: Is lib folder in the path? Try copying the dll to the same folder where the exe exists

Comment: When I run using start without debugging =>No have problem . But I run using press F5 . This is notify 'Flann_Test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Flann_Test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Flann_Test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Flann_Test1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file

Comment: Ok then this can be happen because of visual studio configuration issue. try to use this thread. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/f2d31010-dc89-4290-8869-11bf4a037ea0/

Answer (score 0):

Place the flann.dll in windows directory or in the place where your exe exists